# "Randomness" versus "uncertainty"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, measurement-problem, determinism, randomness

Highly rated PhysicsSE contributor @[CuriousOne](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/56997/curiousone) regularly makes the following claim about quantum mechanics (e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247755/how-are-quantum-computers-able-to-store-any-data-at-all#comment544845_247755)):

> *There is no randomness in quantum mechanics, there is only uncertainty.*

I want to know what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: I think you misquoted?

Comment: A source can emit one photon in a random direction but turn of the energy and the isotropic nature will become more apparent.

Comment: The "no randomness" presumably means he believes in many worlds via decoherence. Judging from your posts, you already know that -- are you looking for a defense of many worlds instead? Or what he specifically thinks about it? If it's the latter you could just chat him...

Comment: If you have a random/probabilistic process, its dynamic can't be reversed. A quantum mechanical process, e.g. a spin system, can be reversed as long as you don't perform a measurement on it. Take a look at spin echos and compare that to the dynamic properties of truly probabilistic systems. It's a day and night difference.

Comment: this question relates to the problem of nonlocality/ "spooky action at a distance" studied by a long string of physicists eg Einstein, Bohm, Bell etc.

Answer (score 3):

*There is no randomness in quantum mechanics, there is only uncertainty.* , as stated, whoever may have said it.

[Mathematical definition of randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness):

> The fields of mathematics, probability, and statistics use formal definitions of randomness. In statistics, a random variable is an assignment of a numerical value to each possible outcome of an event space. This association facilitates the identification and the calculation of probabilities of the events.

So by this definition, mathematically, randomness is defined wherever probability distributions can be assigned to expected outcomes.

As quantum mechanics is par excellence a probabilistic theory, i.e. probability distributions are assigned to measurable variables from solutions of relevant differential equations, this mathematical definition of randomness is not the one used in the statement. It must be the everyday concept in the beginning of the link:

> Randomness is the lack of pattern or predictability in events. A random sequence of events, symbols or steps has no order and does not follow an intelligible pattern or combination.

So the statement *There is no randomness*  can be applied to any event that can be predicted/estimated from a probability distribution, and not only in  quantum mechanics. When a mathematical probability distribution exists, there is only uncertainty for a specific measurement , given in terms of the probability for that outcome.

So the statement should be :

*There is no randomness where a mathematical probability distribution exists, there is only uncertainty* .

So the original is a statement valid in a discussion where deterministic classical theories which predict a single measurement value as the solutions of the appropriate equations are being discussed, whereas quantum mechanics ( or any probabilistic theory)  predicts an uncertain value with a given probability.

The above exposition goes to prove that the context where a  statement is  made is as important as boundary values for  physics solutions.

Comment: Please take a look at the central results of probability theory, which are a number of central limit theorems. Where, in quantum mechanics, do you find central limit theorems to be useful?

Comment: @CuriousOne can you give a link? I can give one central limit theorem for quantum mechanics by googling http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608198

Comment: Serious mathematics textbooks on probability theory should do. See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralLimitTheorem.html for an introduction to the most trivial aspects of it.

Comment: @CuriousOne It seems though that they exist for quantum mechanics  also , which you think it does not

Comment: Central limits? Not really. Can you derive superconductivity from an averaging procedure that results in a Gaussian? How about the energy levels of hydrogen? How do they derive from a Gaussian?

Comment: The relevant central limit theorem would apply to tensor products of quantum states. Think of it as a form of universality in quantum critical phenomena. Or alternatively, universality in thermal quantum systems at finite temperature.

Comment: @fs137: Not even thermodynamics can be reduced to a central limit theorem and the world can not be reduced to thermodynamics, not even for $T\to \infty$. Max Planck discovered that in 1900.

Comment: @CuriousOne the link I gave says  "describes the relation between the quantum central limit theorem ", an note that there exist many probability distributions other than gaussians ( student-t , poisson ..) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions

Comment: You can take any of those distributions and average out over them (in the sense of stochastics), they will all converge (rather rapidly) to Gaussians. Gaussians are, of course, not even the core of thermodynamics. Why does everybody want to reduce to world to one or two phenomena, when we are all making a living by studying the dizzying reality that it is not made out of one or two phenomena, at all?

Comment: No one is trying to squash anything here (I hope).  The central limit theorem is the most famous example of universality, where coarse-graining (implemented through averaging) leads to a unique scaling limit.  In quantum systems, the "coarse-graining" is implemented differently, but involves grouping subsystems together and tracing over microscopic degrees of freedom. The scaling limit is a density matrix, or field theory (though canonically the ground state/DM is most important). (Also, the Cauchy distribution doesn't converge to a Gaussian).

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is subtle, so I'll be careful in how I set up my answer.

In my understanding of quantum mechanics, wave function collapse is the closest a physical process can be to the mathematical idealization of a random variable. However, before the collapse, a [complicated many-body process](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06008.pdf), the wave function evolution of the system is deterministic (unitary). One could say that uncertainty is what characterizes the wave function *before* measurement (measurement being viewed as a kind of dissipative process), while "randomness" characterizes the probabilities of making various measurements, implicitly after any decoherence necessary for measurement has occured.

[Addendum: In the context of quantum computing, it's important to find a set of measurements (quantum numbers used to read the output of the computation) that align as much as possible with the set of (meaningful) final states that the algorithm could produce. If there is some misalignment between the measurement axis and these final states, noise is generated when reading the output.]

Comment: "Wave function collapse" (which us really just a very unfortunate name for the Born rule) requires the system to be open, i.e. exposed to many unknown degrees of freedom. It is "random" because it is physically made to be random.

Comment: I agree. But measurements need to be made, and the collapse of the wave function is what our limited senses are able to observe. Also, all physical systems are open.

Comment: One can observe spin echos just fine. A strong measurement is such a crude operation on a quantum system that many forget how much really fun non-destructive things one can do on them. Part of the problem with QM 101 is that it is being taught in a phenomenological vacuum, whereas a short look into a few textbooks on quantum optics, spin resonance and solid state physics could teach that there is a whole universe of phenomenally useful quantum measurement techniques out there to which strong measurement is but one tiny piece (and in hep it's not used, at all).

Comment: All I am saying is that *physical* randomness that is not a consequence of the observer's ignorance comes from wave function collapse. (You may argue that randomness from wave function collapse is a consequence of ignorance of the many-body wave function of system+environment.)

Comment: Indeed, "wave function collapse" is the observer's _chosen_ ignorance. Not every system is, automatically, a good measurement apparatus. Only those systems that have a sufficient number of unknown degrees of freedom to store the result of an _unbiased_ measurement for "eternity" are.

Comment: Well, most experimentalists I know have good enough memories.

Comment: Have you ever known an experimentalist who was in a quantum superposition with himself? Me neither. Experimentalists are systems with lots of thermodynamic degrees of freedom.

Comment: Now I'm interested in hearing your definition of "thermodynamic degree of freedom". Maybe we should continue this in chat?

Comment: Correction: I think I misinterpreted your idea of a good measurement apparatus earlier. Wouldn't *you* (and all your thermodynamic degrees of freedom) need to perform many measurements to get enough information about the system to interpret results from your ideal measurement apparatus? How would it not just propagate the state of the original system into a new kind of representation?

Comment: The difference between quantum mechanical degrees of freedom and thermodynamic (stochastic) degrees of freedom is made explicit in the theory of the density matrix. The definition of a "good" measurement apparatus is one which has an "infinite memory" and which produces a result that can be interpreted in some physical sense. It's as much an "I know it when I see it" as a Newtonian force is. Not trying to get into a general philosophical discussion here. We know how to design "good measurement apparatus" and it starts with intuition and a hardware catalog, not an operator.

Comment: I see. Well, it sounds to me like your are explaining how to perform weak measurements. If I were attempting this, my goal would probably be to use weak measurements to reconstruct the wave function (operating under the belief that the system is in a pure state).  However, unless I already *knew* the wave function (or had some knowledge about its possible states, cf. statement about QC in my answer), I would need to perform at least a few strong measurements to learn what the wave function is. Otherwise, quantum tomography would be very simple.

Comment: Weak measurements don't reconstruct the wave function. The weak measurements that nature performs all the time reduce some aspects of quantum theory to some aspects of classical mechanics. And some aspects of quantum mechanics aren't being reduced by anything, at all (e.g. the existence of matter). "The wave function" is a reductionist view that loses almost all of the actual richness inherent in nature by pretending that everything is either a closed system or a hammer that squashes it flat into a projective subspace. Seriously... reality is a lot more interesting than that.

Comment: Correction: weak measurements (in the sense of a measurement that does not disturb the wave function significantly) plus unitary transformations can be used to reconstruct the wave function, as long as 'enough' weak measurements can be performed without causing the initial state to decohere. (Also, are you completely sure you don't want this discussion to be philosophical?)

Comment: To me this isn't philosophical, at all. I have done plenty of "weak" measurements in my life, I just used to call them "a particle detector". Unlike some of my colleagues I had the good fortune to know what "a particle detector" was actually doing. Not that it matters, one can design really good particle detectors without ever realizing that their low level function was well grasped by Mott in 1929, who at the same time gave the proper limit between the quantum world and CM as he was the first to describe a practically important weak measurement limit. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne, I'm really enjoying this discussion and I'm a little worried about how long it's getting (so maybe it would be good to move to chat). In your particle detector example, the ensemble of weak measurements (of various types, depending on instrumentation, collision, and energy scale) is what gives you detailed information about microscopic interactions. Would you agree that measurements like these need to be made to get information about a system, and that by Landauer's principle they must involve some level of decoherence?

Comment: Detailed information? From a particle detector??? We wish. No offense, but they are some of the least precise experiments ever built and can't be anything else by principle. Some I have helped building are considered successful if they get the order of magnitude of the particle energy right. :-)

Comment: Of course, a weak measurement gives hardly any information about a particular event or system. I was just giving a general reminder that the parameters for a quantum mechanical model can be tightly constrained by ensembles of measurements.